# Python code unable to read environment variables that are set

Tags: python, slack, bolt

Code

```
app=App(
    token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN1"),
    signing_secret=os.environ.get("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET1")
)
```

CMD

Able to see values when i do echo

```
echo %SLACK_BOT_TOKEN1%

echo %SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET1%
```

Error Output

```
  File "C:/Users/A6002043/PycharmProjects/workflow-steps/app.py", line 12, in <module>
    app=App(
  File "C:\Users\A6002043\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\slack_bolt\app\app.py", line 110, in __init__
    raise BoltError(error_signing_secret_not_found())
slack_bolt.error.BoltError: Signing secret not found, so could not initialize the Bolt app.Copy your Signing Secret from the Basic Information page and then store it in a new environment variable
```

Comment: Are you running the code from the _same_ environment where the variables are set?

Comment: Are you using a python virtual environment?  That is the kind of error I get when I forget to activate my virtual environment.